# MoveIt detect collision for disabled links in SRDF

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, gripper, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I’m new to this community so if I’ve made some mistakes please let me know. My problem description is as follows:

I created a new arm+sensor+gripper URDF and used the MoveIt Setup Assistant to generate a MoveIt config package. When I use MoveGroup to move the arm I get this error:

```
Found a contact between 'gripper_finger1_inner_knuckle_link' (type 'Robot link') and 'gripper_finger1_finger_tip_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
```

In my SRDF these 2 links are disabled:

```
<disable_collisions link1="gripper_finger1_finger_tip_link" link2="gripper_finger1_inner_knuckle_link" reason="Adjacent" />
```

I’ve also tried updating the allowed collision matrix by updating the planning scene diff and then call `apply_planning_scene` service.

At this point I’m not sure what else to try. I hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic. MoveIt is installed from deb

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342686/moveit-detect-collision-for-disabled-links-in-srdf/) by [truhoang_ubtrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/51274/truhoang_ubtrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out what I did wrong: I updated the allowed collision matrix in the planning scene and I think this overrides the disabled collisions in the SRDF. Commenting out that part of my code resolves this issue.

---

Originally posted by [truhoang_ubtrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/51274/truhoang_ubtrobot/) with karma: 16 on 2020-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0